# I just uploaded an app on playstore but there's an error in downloading on some devices?

Tags: android, google-play-services

this is the error while downloading on some android phones
Is there any code related issue?

[image]

Comment: This question would be better asked on serverfault... It's not code related. Posts like this could easily promote malware as people install the app to work out what's wrong.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.xxx.xxxx">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <application
------------------------
-------------------
/>
```

Add this in Manifest below permission and above  `<application/>` Tag

Comment: Inside <application> tagg?

Comment: Could you explain why you believe this would fix the problem?

Comment: Let me check another alternate solution

Answer (score 0):

According to the [list of status codes at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) this means that:

```
504 Gateway Timeout
The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and did not receive a timely response from the upstream server.
In other words: the culprit should neither be (on) your device, nor (at) Google Play -- but in between.
```

In order to fix it you have some methods:

Method 1:

- Clear data
- Clear cache of google play store & google service framework

Method 2:

- Remove your google account
- Reboot
- Re-add account

If it doesn't work it cloud be related to the device lack of space for example.

Comment: Did you have that app installed on your device previously?